# Using a Class Module public variable withevents

Tags: vba, userform

I have a userform1 with calendar. Each day is formed by a label. When clicking on a label, call a class module that identifies the clicked label and records its caption:

```
Public WithEvents Frme As MSForms.Label
Public frm As UserForm

Private Sub Frme_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
'here i want call a userform2
End Sub
```

I need call a userform2 to show the activities that have that day, but I can't link the Frme variable with the userform2. I ask for help

I don't have much knowledge in class module although I've researched a lot on the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the selected label's caption to Userform2 by declaring a public variable in the class module and setting its value before calling Userform2. In the Userform2 module, you can retrieve the value of this variable to show the activities of the selected day. Here's an example of how you can modify the code:

In the class module:

```
Public WithEvents Frme As MSForms.Label
Public frm As UserForm
Public SelectedDate as String

Private Sub Frme_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
SelectedDate = Frme.Caption
UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

In the Userform2 module:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
'Use the SelectedDate variable to retrieve and show activities for that day
End Sub
```

By setting the value of the SelectedDate variable in the class module before calling Userform2, you can retrieve it in the Userform2 module to show the activities for that day. You can declare the variable in Main module but i think it's better in the class module.

Comment: Ty for reply! In fact the variable in the class module records the value of the Frme, but when I call the SelectedDate variable in the userform2 it comes up empty. What am I doing wrong? As an example, in userform2 I put a=SelectedDate and had empty as a result. Please, help me.

Comment: `Public SelectedDate as String` should be in a regular module.

Comment: ...the userform doesn't have any reference to the specific instance of the event-capturing class which showed the form.

Comment: Oh yeah! It´s done. Thank you very much both

Answer (score 1):

Add a Property/Public variable `SelectedDate` to `UserForm2`. Then you can do something like this:

```vb
Private Sub Frme_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, _
                           ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Dim frm As UserForm2 'see https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/
    Set frm = New UserForm2         'create an instance of UserForm2
    frm.SelectedDate = Frme.Caption 'or however you get the date
    frm.Show                        'show the instance

End Sub
```